# Not receiving DM’s in twitter stream

Tags: node.js, twitter, nodes, twitter-streaming-api

I have an app with the following permissions: 'Read, Write and Access direct messages'. Using the twitter stream i receive all other events/data such tweets, unfollows etc. But not direct_message. The account associated with my app is following the message sending user and vice versa. I can also verify via www that the messages make it through. The app account only has one follower which is account where I am sending from.

I am using the twit nodejs library: https://github.com/ttezel/twit#event-direct_message

```
stream.on('direct_message', function(direct_message) {
  console.log('direct_message',direct_message);
}
```

Suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 2):

turns out that i just to wait aftrer I changed my app permission. it took a bit for the permission change to propagate.